# How to send data from android application to mac by usb cable

Tags: android, android-usb

I have no information about usb cable transfer so everything comes me strange.

For example, i install the application on two different device. And than these two devices are connected the usb cable. When i launch the applications. I can transfer data between applications. I write "hello world" in one device, and other device's application show me "hello world". This is basically what i want to do.

I googled lots of but i have only found code parts not whole project or example that has total information. And this code snippets does not mean anything to me.

[Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) has not even full information about that.

Secondly i have found [usb-serial-for-android](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) library. But when i run demo project application does no match my mac.

I added product_id and vendor_id to device_filter.xml

```
   <usb-device
    product-id="0x8289"
    vendor-id="0x05AC" />
```

I have found this data in my mac terminal by writing

```
system_profiler -detailLevel full
```

So any idea? Any knowledgeable friend ? Or any person that points some links where i start from beginning?